# Why can't I create NTFS partition in extended section?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ntfs

I have unallocated space of 196 GB as you can see.
And I want to create NTFS partition for it to be used in Windows10.
But I get this error.

Before installing I had a big partition in NTFS I delete it and create a smaller logical partition for 50gb for Ubuntu and I want to use the rest for data storage but it give me this error.

I heard we can create as many partition in extended but I can't create any.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The unallocated space is outside the extended partition. It means that when you try to create a partition, you are trying to create a fifth primary partition, and it is not possible with an MSDOS partition table.

- Instead you can grow the extended partition (increase the size), so that it reaches the end of the drive.
- After that the unallocated space will be inside the extended partition. And you will be able to create an NTFS partition.

Comment: and sir how do i do that?

Comment: With gparted, that you are already using. Right-click on the area that you want to edit and you can do it graphically. If you want detailed help, maybe this link will help you, http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/GrowIt.pdf

Comment: I went to see in windows and there is still that partition in windows.But when i open files from it it says it doesn't exist.isn't there any easy way to do that ?

Comment: Is there a partition, that Windows can see, but not linux? This is strange. Please edit your original question to add a picture showing what Windows can see. (Maybe something is wrong in the partition table.)

Comment: Hello the problem is resolved i load LIve disc and try ubuntu then.i Resize the extended partition to max unallocated then i create NTFS partiiton and format it and now i can see NTFS partition in windows as well.Did i do something wrong it shows in windows disk management as Logical 196GB partition.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem :-) Partitions in the extended partition are logical partitions, so I think it is good.